# How to validate XML document against its XSD schema using SaxonJ-HE 11 (Saxon 11 Home Edition for Java)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saxon, xsd-validation

I am looking at [**Product Description for SaxonJ-HE (Home Edition)** pdf document](https://www.saxonica.com/products/PD11/SaxonJ-HE.pdf) and on page 4, section "**Interfaces and APIs**" it says:

```
13. JAXP API
Implementations of the standard JAXP interfaces for XSLT transformation, XPath evaluation, and XML Schema validation.
```

[image]

Does that mean I can validate XML message against XSD schema using API included in Home Edition? Does anyone know how?

Comment: The Java platform/JRE usually comes with some built-in version of Apache Xerces to do XSD 1.0 schema validation so you can do that with Java, whether you use XSLT or not. Recent standalone releases of Xerces also support XSD 1.1. Saxon HE itself does not provide any XSD validation features, for that you would need to use Saxon EE (e.g. request a trial license or buy a commercial license).

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm sorry, that's misleading and I'll get it fixed.

While the JAXP and s9api APIs allow you to request schema validation, Saxon-HE does not include a schema validator so the request will fail.

You can of course use the Xerces schema validator which is open source, but it doesn't integrate with Saxon.

Comment: The document on the web site has now been fixed.